# Conflict between the TikZ-library quotes and babel package, why does \usetikzlibrary{babel} not help?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, quotation

When trying the following MWE,

```
\usetikzlibrary {babel,graphs,quotes}
\tikz \graph {
a ->["x"] b ->["y"'] c ->["z" red] d;
};
```

with `\RequirePackage[swedish, english]{babel}` in my class, I get errors like this for each use of quotes:

```
! Use of \tikz@quote@@parser doesn't match its definition.
<argument> "
            {x}"={\pgfkeysnovalue }
l.10 }
      ;
```

If I remove the `swedish` option from `babel`, there is no issue.

Why does `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` not help in this case?

---

After looking at other questions regarding `babel` and `tikz` I found that the following modification works

```
\shorthandoff{"}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,quotes}
\shorthandon{"}

\tikz \graph {
a ->["x"] b ->["y"'] c ->["z" red] d;
};
```

but

```
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,quotes}

\shorthandoff{"}
\tikz \graph {
a ->["x"] b ->["y"'] c ->["z" red] d;
};
\shorthandon{"}
```

does not.

My TikZ version is 3.1.5b.

Note: An alternative way to get edge labels without the quotes library is to use the option `[edge label=x]`, but that is more cumbersome.

Comment: Delete the `\usepackage` and `RequirePackage` in your thesis template, line-by-line, until the error disappear. You may also delete things like `\newtheorem`. Once your thesis template is <100 lines left then consider post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been avoiding that approach since the template is spread over a dozen files, but maybe line-by-line elimination of packages is the only way to isolate such issues?

Comment: I didn't know thesis template can be more than one file (feeling sorry about that). But yeah, maybe you can start from deleting `\input{defendants.tex}` so it will quickly reduce to one file. Before that, here is a blind guess: the `quote` library is a hacky one because (IIRC) it lets the `catcode` of `"` be 13 and interferes how `pgfkeys` works. If your template files plays with the catcode, too, then boom.

Comment: Maybe I should have written thesis class instead of template. :) I'll see if I will muster the energy to go through the thesis class tomorrow. I think your guess is good given the other issues relating to babel/polyglossia, but I'm a bit out of my depth TeX-wise.

Comment: The issue came from using ```babel``` with swedish as an option, which surprised me a bit as I thought the tikz-library babel would avoid that. So I rewrote the question quite a bit and added a workaround.